# Proving this function is negative for all $x\in[0,\infty)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functions, derivatives

I want to prove that the function

$$f(x)=\frac{(2x+ab-1)\ln\left(\frac{ac-(1-x)}{ab-(1-x)}\right)}{a}+\frac{(b-1)(ac-1)}{ac-(1-x)}+\frac{(2b-c-1)x}{ac-(1-x)}$$ is negative for all $x \in [0,\infty)$.

The parameters here satisfy the following:

$$a>1,\quad\frac{1}{a}<b<1,\quad b<c<1$$

I proved so far that $f(0)<c-1<0$ with the help of the inequality $\ln(1+x)<x$ and also that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x)=c-1<0.$$

However, when I'm trying to apply it in general, by using the inequality $\ln(1+x)<x$ once, I get:

$$\begin{align}f(x)&<(c-b)+\frac{(c-b)x}{ab-(1-x)}+(b-1)\left(1-\frac{x}{ac-(1-x)}\right)+\frac{(2b-c-1)x}{ac-(1-x)}\\&=(c-1)+\frac{a(c-b)^{2}}{(ab-(1-x))(ac-(1-x))}\end{align}$$

So I'm getting stuck here. Maybe there is another approach that is better to use in that case but can't see it. By making two simulations, it looks like $f(x)$ might be an increasing function but failed to prove it also in general. Even if I can prove that $f(x)$ is negative on $[0,1]$ for sure at least can be enough. Help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is in fact possible to prove the stricter result that $g(x)=f(x)-(c-1)$ is negative on its natural domain $D=(-\infty,1-ac)\cup(1-bc,\infty)$ (the argument of the natural logarithm must be positive). We will prove this by showing $g''(x)$ is negative on $D$ and therefore that $g'(x)$ monotonically decreases on $D$; using the limit of $g'(x)$ as $x\to\pm \infty$ to argue that $g'(x)$ is negative on $(-\infty,1-ac)$ and positive on $(1-bc,\infty)$, meaning $g(x)$ is monotonously decreasing and monotonously increasing on these respective intervals; and conclude that $g(x)<0$ for all $x\in D$ by taking the limit of $g(x)$ as $x\to\pm \infty$.

Consideration of the natural domain of $g$ motivates introducing the constants $B=ab-1$, $C=ac-1$ such that $D=\mathbb{R}\setminus[-C,-B]$. The constraints on $a,b,c$ then imply that $B\in(0,a-1)$ and $C\in(B,a-1)$. Rewriting $g(x)$ by eliminating $b,c$ in terms of $B,C$ and subsequently differentiating twice yields
$$g''(x)=-\frac{(B+2C)(C-B)^2}{a} \frac{\left(x+ \frac{C(2B+C)}{B+2C}\right)^2 +\frac{C^2(5B^3+5B^2C+3BC^2-C^3)}{(B+2C)^2(C-B)} }{(C+x)^4(B+x)^2}\tag{1},$$ from which it can be seen that the sign of $g''(x)$ is opposite the sign of $$\left(x+\frac{C(2B+C)}{B+2C}\right)^2 + \frac{C^2(5B^3+5B^2C+3BC^2-C^3)}{(B+2C)^2(C-B)} \tag{2}.$$ By viewing $(2)$ as a quadratic equation in $x$, it is possible to show that $(2)$ is positive for all $x \in D$ (explicitly, the real root(s) of $(2)$, if they exist, can be shown to fall in $[-C,-B]=\mathbb{R}\setminus D$ and so if there is $x\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $(2)$ is non-positive, $x \notin D$). This establishes that $g''(x)$ is negative on $D$ and therefore that $g'(x)$ monotonically decreases on $D$.

It can be shown that $\lim\limits_{x\to \pm \infty} g'(x)=0$. Using this together with the fact that $g'(x)$ is monotonically decreasing on $D$, we require that $g'(x)$ is negative on $(-\infty,-C)$ and positive on $(-B,\infty)$. This means $g(x)$ monotonically decreases on $(-\infty,-C)$ and monotonically increases on $(-B,\infty)$.

Lastly, since $g(x)=f(x)-(c-1)$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to \pm \infty}f(x)=c-1$ as you stated for $x \to +\infty$, we have that $$\lim\limits_{x\to \pm \infty}g(x)=\lim\limits_{x\to \pm \infty}[f(x)]-(c-1)=(c-1)-(c-1)=0.$$
This completes the proof because we know $g(x)$ monotonically decreases on $(-\infty,-C)$ starting from $0$ in the $x\to -\infty$ limit and monotonically increases on $(-B,\infty)$ ending at $0$ in the $x\to \infty$ limit, thereby showing that it must be negative on all of $D$ as desired.

The key strategy here is using $g''(x)$ to reason about $g'(x)$ to reason about $g(x)$. It is generally useful to consider the second derivative of a function when it is difficult to show that function is monotonically increasing/decreasing directly from its first derivative.

Comment: Please, I'd like an explanation about the quadratic expression in (2). It is basically the heart of your proof, yet I can't see why this expression really is positive.

Comment: Never mind, I already proved it thoroughly and got the result. Thanks a lot for the approach! It really is interesting!

Comment: Most definitely! For reference, one way of showing that $(2)$ is positive on $D$ is by noting that $(2)$ must achieve its minimum on $D$ as $x\to-C^-$ or $x\to-B^+$ since $(2)$ is concave up and its vertex is at $x=\frac{-C(2B+C)}{B+2C} \in (-C,-B)$. Direct computation then shows that $(2)$ has a minimal value of $\frac{4B^2C^2}{(B+2C)(C-B)}>0$ on $(-\infty,-C]\cup[-B,\infty)$ at $x=-C$.